# Does the ReSharper API expose ReSharper refactorings?

Tags: resharper, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

I'd like to know if the ReSharper API exposes the refactorings that come with the ReSharper plugin. So far I haven't been able to find anything on this in the docs or online. Basically I want to be able to execute several refactorings sequentially (almost like a script). I'm aware that the API allows you to create new refactorings, but I'm not sure if it allows for invoking refactorings that already exist in ReSharper.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean when you say "refactorings"? Do you refer specifically to what ReSharper itself calls refactorings (commands available under *ReSharper | Refactor* or the *Refactor This* menu), or in a more general sense to all ReSharper's code transformation commands that are available via *Alt+Entter*?

Comment: @Jura Gorohovsky I'm referring to the former, what ReSharper calls "refactorings" (i.e. the refactorings noted [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Main_Set_of_Refactorings.html).